# How do I present a pull-down menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenu

I'm looking to add a pull-down menu and I have no idea where to start. Apple's [website](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/) guides me to UIMenu but I can't figure out how it works.

I know how to make a UIMenu:

```
NSMutableArray* actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Edit"
                                       image:nil
                                  identifier:nil
                                     handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
    
    // ...
}]];

UIMenu* menu =
[UIMenu menuWithTitle:@""
             children:actions];
```

How do I attach it to a UIButton?

Comment: "I can't find the menu builder"... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenubuilder?language=objc

Comment: There's no UIMenuBuilder class or object in Xcode I don't know where to access it. Even if I knew I don't know how to present the menu.

Comment: Did you read the page I linked you to? It answers both of those questions directly, right there on the page.

Comment: You are supposed to override this function: buildMenuWithBuilder but I have no idea where. I'm not trying to get spoon fed.

Comment: Maybe I've messed things up. This is what I'm trying to achieve and I can only find swift code: https://medium.com/ivymobility-developers/context-menus-in-ios-226727a8aa88

Comment: But that's not a system menu. It's a context menu. You don't use a builder for that.

Comment: Did you want this menu to appear in response to pressing on a view? Then you give that view a UIContextMenuInteraction. Just like in the tutorial you're pointing to. You have given no information as to how _you_ expect _your_ menu to appear, so it's impossible to say more.

Comment: OK, I figured context menus and added the solution to the main post. This is what I was actually aiming for but I didn't know what was its name: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/

Comment: If you scroll a bit you 'll see it refers to UIMenu. What!?

Comment: Very confusing. Now you've got some code and no question. What's the question at this point? Was that supposed to be the answer? Then don't put it in the question, put it in an answer.

Comment: I was looking for a context menu. I found the context menu. Turns out I was looking for a pull-down menu. These two look almost the same. I will use the context menu anyway for some other interactions.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: It sounds like a wild goose chase.

Comment: The question is: "How do I present a pull-down menu?"

Comment: What _is_ a "pull-down menu" in your terminology? Do you mean a button where a menu appears when you long-press the button? If so, a UIButton has a `menu`; you assign a UIMenu to it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3601189-menu

Comment: It's not my terminology, it's how Apple named it: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/

Comment: Not long press, just a single tap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems, after several radical rewrites of your question, that you want a menu that appears from a button. Well, a UIButton has a `menu` property and you assign a UIMenu to it. Done.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3601189-menu?language=objc

If you also want the menu to appear as a response to a simple tap, rather than a long press, then also set the button's `showsMenuAsPrimaryAction` property to YES.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/3601223-showsmenuasprimaryaction?language=objc

(A UIBarButtonItem has similar properties, in case you want to make the menu appear that way.)

Comment: solution not working for me

Comment: Thats seems to be what I'm looking for bu the UIMenu documentation doesn't open in objective c . can't understand the example code in UIMenu doc (which is in Swift)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on matt's answer, here is some example code in Objective-C:

```
// Add a UIMenu (with three actions) to a UIButton
NSMutableArray  *theMenuActions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

[theMenuActions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FullName", @"")
                                              image:nil
                                         identifier:@"search_scope_full"
                                            handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
self.mySearchScope  = @"full";
}]];
    
[theMenuActions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FirstName", @"")
                                              image:nil
                                         identifier:@"search_scope_first"
                                            handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
self.mySearchScope  = @"first";
}]];

[theMenuActions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LastName", @"")
                                              image:nil
                                         identifier:@"search_scope_last"
                                            handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
self.mySearchScope  = @"last";
}]];

// searchScopeBtn is a UIButton
self.searchScopeBtn.menu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"SearchScope", @"") 
                                        children:theMenuActions];
self.searchScopeBtn.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = YES;

// When the UIButton is tapped, the UIMenu will appear
```